# How to run SQL queries using Apache Kyuubi and Apache Spark but with different Spark driver and executor configurations?

Tags: apache-spark, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run SQL queries using Apache Kyuubi (Backed by Apache Spark) while having different Spark configurations such driver cores/memory and executors core/memory/count for each SQL query. To save time, I'm trying to do this without setting those configurations and then restarting Kyuubi and Spark to apply those configurations.

I understand that some Spark configurations cannot be changed after creating the Spark driver, such as executors cores/memory/count, driver cores/memory and possibly other configurations too.

That's why I believe it's best to specify these configurations while defining Kyuubi's JDBC connection URL, and to specify Spark's application name to create a new application and driver for each query. I understand that this can be extremely expensive but I'm doing this for experimental purposes only.

Some of the assumptions I just stated could be wrong, so I appreciate if you correct them for me please.

Now my question is how can I specify those Spark configurations in Apache Kyuubi's connection URL? I'm using Python and SQL Alchemy 1.4.48.

Kyuubi's connection URL described [here](https://kyuubi.readthedocs.io/en/master/configuration/settings.html#via-jdbc-connection-url) didn't work for me as it threw an error implying that the arguments where assumed to be part of the schema name!
For example, if I specify the connection URL as ``, I face the following error:

```
Schema [`SALES;#spark.executor.memory=4g;spark.executor.cores=2;spark.executor.instances=2;spark.driver.memory=4g;spark.driver.cores=2;spark.app.name=naming_test_1696497965.1731281`] does not exist, or user admin does not have access to it.
```

Where `SALES` is the schema name.

Here is the piece of code that is failing for me:

```
pool_args = {'connect_args': {'auth': 'LDAP', 'username': self.arguments.kyuubi_username, 'password': self.arguments.kyuubi_password},
                 'echo': False, 'echo_pool': True}
spark_config = {
        'spark.executor.memory': '4g',
        'spark.executor.cores': '2',
        'spark.executor.instances': '2',
        'spark.driver.memory': '4g',
        'spark.driver.cores': '2',
        'spark.app.name': 'naming_test_' + str(time.time()),
    }
    connection_url = self.arguments.kyuubi_url + ';#' + ';'.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in spark_config.items()])
    self.engine = sql.create_engine(connection_url, **pool_args)
```

So what am I doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the client-side behavior cannot parse the connection_url to obtain the host, port, and configurations, similar to a JDBC Driver.

You can refer to the API documentation on how to pass configurations for establishing a connection with the Kyuubi server.

For example, if you use pyhive

```
from pyhive import hive
hive.connect('10.221.103.23', port='10009', configuration={'spark.abc':'123'})
```